# force download of pdf only as pdfs open first then permit download

Tags: php

I have a script that allows the download of files the user selects from a specific directory, everything works ok, but pdf files open first then you can download it, I need to force download of the pdf as soon as the link to the file is clicked.

I have included the a href attribute of the script, I tried adding download to the href without success, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<A HREF="'. $_SESSION["dir2"] ."/". $new_array[$i][0] . '">' .  $new_array[$i][0] .  "</A>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the download attribute:

```
<a href="'. $_SESSION["dir2"] ."/". $new_array[$i][0] . '" download>' .  $new_array[$i][0] .  "</a>
```

Comment: adding the download to href works perfectly!

Comment: thank you, but you could found that in google too :)